# App is not coming in full frame on iPhone 5C

Tags: ios, ios8

I am working on an Universal application. I am implementing the frame of content with coding & XIB. Its running successfully in all device but iPhone 5C its not coming with full Frame. Its coming like as iPhone 4, 4S screen. I share the screenshot Please anybody can find out whats my problem ?

[image]

Top bar and buttom bar is coming Black color. Its not fitted with Screen. Please suggest me.

Comment: did you try to add default launch image for 4inch screen see [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/12/31/retina-4-support.html) ?

Comment: Add Launch images for 4 inch screen, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add splash screen for 4" iPhone devices.